# With Webdriver, how do I click a button that has a data-bind 'mousedown' event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, webdriver-io

I am using [WebdriverIO](http://webdriver.io/api.html) and WebdriverCSS to create a visual regression test suite.

The page I am currently testing has a form with a submit button, however, when I send try to click on this button, the form is not submitted.

The HTML for the button is below

```
<div class="submit_jump_patch" data-bind="event: {'mousedown': $root.formSubmitHandler }">
    <input type="submit" name="journey_save" value="Next" id="journey_save" class="btn btn_primary btn_large float_right full_width_m" data-bind="css : { 'spinner' : showSpinner, 'disabled' : disableSubmit }, attr: { 'aria-busy' : showSpinner() ? 'true' : 'false' }" aria-busy="false">
</div>
```

I have tried the following webdriverIO commands:
.click
.moveToObject.click()
.execute (

Unfortunately I am unable to change the HTML so that it doesn't require the 'mousedown' event, and I am unsure why it is there in the first place.

Comment: If I put in an explicit wait of 1 second in before the .click command, this works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using selectorExecute

```
browser.selectorExecute(".submit_jump_patch", function (submitDiv) {
            submitDiv[0].mousedown();
        });
```